# Detecting specific words in a custom android keyboard?

Tags: java, android

I've created a custom android keyboard in Android Studio, and trying to get the keyboard to display a message if a certain word is typed. Any ideas how i am supposed to do this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.